# Entity Framework 6, .NET Framework 4.0 and SaveChangesAsync

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I am developing on `VS2012`, targeting `.NET Framework 4.0` and using `EF6`.

I have installed Nuget packages from Microsoft.

```
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.8" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
 <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
```

I'd like to save changes to database asynchroniously.
I found there is `Await` available but I cannot find `SaveChangesAsync`.

**What do I need to do to enable async operations with Framework 4.0 ?**

*(I cannot upgrage to Framework 4.5 and need to stick with 4.0)*

Comment: likely they compiled it out so its not available.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` functions are not included in the .Net 4.0-compiled EF assembly, so you'll have to use a `Task` in which you call `SaveChanges`.

Excerpt from EF's source code:

```
#if !NET40

        public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
        ...

        public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        ...

#endif
```

So you could create a method like this one:

```
public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(MyDbContext context)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.SaveChanges());
}
```

I assume you're aware of the fact that a `DbContext` is not thread safe, so you'll have to make sure that the context isn't used for other database interactions in the mean time.

Comment: What to put inside the function(s) to make saving changes happen asynchronously? Calling SaveChanges() touches the database still synchronously?

Comment: Of course, but the code outside the Task runs on, unless you explicitly wait for the Task to finish.

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure, the final function should look like this?: public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
 _context.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: @user2143213 if you want to use async IO this will not achieve that.

Comment: I want to have UI not freezing when writing to database.

Comment: @user2143213 in that case you don't need async IO and this answer will help you.

Comment: Hmmm... this is one of those rare cases that I care about a downvote. Downvoter, did I miss something?

Comment: @GertArnold probably because this is the async-over-sync anti-pattern. The pattern is justified here, though.