# ToListAsync not available

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, async-await

I am using Microsoft.BCL.Async in a .Net 4.0 application. I have created an entity framework (version 6) model and am trying to materialise a query against it using .ToListAsync. ToListAsync isn't being recognised though - there's no intellisense for it, and ignoring this gives an error that it's not a member of IQueryAble(Of ...). I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Here's a simple example of the usage:

```
  Private Async Function FetchData() As Tasks.Task
    Using session As New TestEntities
      Dim data = Await session.Clients.ToListAsync
    End Using
  End Function
```

Should I be able to use ToListAsync in the above scenario, and if so what might I be missing to get it working? ToList *is* available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though it's not possible - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743444/entity-framework-6-net-framework-4-0-and-savechangesasync). Instead you have to wrap the data access in its own task, and await that instead. It's not quite the same result, but does achieve what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to import System.Data.Entity - it's an extension method within that assembly.

Comment: Only if you are using .Net 4.5 or above - as stated in the question I am using .Net 4.0